# Cache-Control : no-cache

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, fetch

I tried to build an app in android studio which does json parsing from a URL server with ports (example: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx). So I found 3 methods such as asynctask, volley and okhttp. But the problem is everytime I parse it with these methods, the same exception always occurred.

> java.net.ProtocalException: Unexpected status line: HTTP/1.1 Cache-Control:no-cache

Here is my code

```
 class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

            viewId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ID) ;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlWebService);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String json;

                while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(json + "\n");
                }

                JSONObject data = new JSONObject(sb.toString().trim());

                return sb.toString().trim();

            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                resp = e.getMessage();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), resp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0);
                        toast.show();

                    }
                });
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String rawData) {
            super.onPostExecute(rawData);
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            viewId.setText(rawData);
        }


    }
```

So is there any method to do this parsing? Or any solution?

Comment: seems the problem is in the web service you're requesting. is it implemented by you? if yes, post it here as well

Comment: It is actually not implemented by me. But i do think that the problem is with the web service. I tried to open the URL with Chrome and Firefox and it works. But when I tried with Internet Explorer, it just load forever.

Comment: is it a publicly available service? it would be nice if we could reproduce the error

Comment: Yes, infact it is accessible from any network connection. Unfortunately, I dont think I am allowed to share the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so apparently the problem was not with the code I am using, but the server API's responses. The server didn't response when I hit the API but now it's working perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use postman and use the method `GET`. If it doesnt work, probably there is something wrong with your URL. And also try to see your cache control of both your URL and android studio.

Answer (score 0):

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

use this In Your Manifest

DEMO:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".Home.Pages.viewPages.Extra.CancelAlertActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Home.HomeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MapsActivity" />
```

Comment: I have added it since the beginning of my code so I dont think that's the problem.

Comment: // First set the default cookie manager.
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
// All the following subsequent URLConnections will use the same cookie manager.
URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
connection = new URL(url).openConnection();

Comment: Still I got the same exception. I am pretty sure the problem is when the app is creating a connection with the server.